# Timezone issue in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I've never had this before, but somehow when I'm combining a date and a time to a concatenated datetime and store it in the db, I'm off by 2 hours. I just noticed when I started using time_ago_in_words, it's always two hours from now when I just saved something new.

Any idea how to overcome this differnece. I think this is the code that's responsible for the difference:

```
  def create_timestamp
    self.date = day.to_datetime + time.seconds_since_midnight.seconds
  end
```

In case anyone is wondering, I'm using a seperate date & time picker on my form, so this the before_save method to create one timestamp for the user input.

Upon request, the SQL for an INSERT at 10:47 CEST, Rails app is in UTC btw:

```
INSERT INTO "reports" ("account_id", "description", "report_category_id", "day", "time", "user_id", "date", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9) RETURNING "id"  [["account_id", 2], ["description", ""], ["report_category_id", 4], ["day", "2016-07-30"], ["time", "2000-01-01 10:47:00.000000"], ["user_id", 1], ["date", "2016-07-30 10:47:00.000000"], ["created_at", "2016-07-30 08:47:53.828175"], ["updated_at", "2016-07-30 08:47:53.828175"]]
```

Comment: Could you include the SQL `UPDATE` or `INSERT` query that your application generates? You can get it from the log. Also, the table structure would be useful. Please also state what database server you're using. You can do it in the tags.

Comment: Could you show us the value/class of day and time?

Comment: I updated the question with INSERT statement. And day = Date class, time = Time class. For values, see INSERT.